# google map marker floats when clicked error in console null value innherHTML

Tags: html, asp.net, google-maps

I wanted to make this:[Check this!!](http://www.improve-my-city.com/livedemo/report/) 
First map gets user's location then on dragging marker the location will be passed to textbox, also user can enter the location in textbox and when user clicks on find button the marker will show that location in map. To achieve this I made some changes and now my map don't work. I tried the prev code which was working but same error.

Asp.NET code:

```
     <asp:TextBox ID="txtLoc" CssClass="form-control" 
     runat="server" Style="width: 390px"></asp:TextBox>

     <asp:Button ID="btnFind" runat="server" 
     CssClass="btn btn-info btn-xs" 
     Text="Find location on map">  </asp:Button>
```

.js code

```
var geocoder;

function initMap() {
geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();
if (navigator.geolocation) {
    navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(showPosition, showError);
} else {
    x = document.getElementById("cpdMain_cpdCitizenProfile_txtLoc");
    x.innerHTML = "Geolocation is not supported by this browser.";
}

function showError(error) {
    x = document.getElementById("cpdMain_cpdCitizenProfile_txtLoc");
    switch (error.code) {
        case error.PERMISSION_DENIED:
            x.innerHTML = "User denied the request for Geolocation."
            break;
        case error.POSITION_UNAVAILABLE:
            x.innerHTML = "Location information is unavailable."
            break;
        case error.TIMEOUT:
            x.innerHTML = "The request to get user location timed  out."
            break;
        case error.UNKNOWN_ERROR:
            x.innerHTML = "An unknown error occurred."
            break;
    }
}



//updateMarkerPosition(latlon);
//geocodePosition(latlon);
 }

 function geocodePosition(pos) {
x = document.getElementById("cpdMain_cpdCitizenProfile_txtLoc");
geocoder.geocode({ 'latLng': pos }, function (results, status) {
    if (status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {
        if (results[0]) {
            x.innerHTML = results[0].formatted_address;
            y = document.getElementById("cpdMain_cpdCitizenProfile_txtLoc");
            y.value = results[0].formatted_address;


        }
    } else {
        x.innerHTML = "Geocoder non possibile";
    }
     });

       }

function showPosition(position) {
lat = position.coords.latitude;
lon = position.coords.longitude;
latlon = new google.maps.LatLng(lat, lon)
mapholder = document.getElementById('map')

var myOptions = {
    center: latlon,
    zoom: 14,
    mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP,
    mapTypeControl: false,
    navigationControlOptions:
    { style: google.maps.NavigationControlStyle.SMALL }
}

var contentString = 'Drag red marker <br/> to improve geo-location';
var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
    content: contentString
});
infowindow.open(map, marker);

var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map"), myOptions);
var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
    position: latlon,
    map: map,
    title: 'Report refers to this location',
    draggable: true
});


// Add dragging event listeners.
google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'dragstart', function (evt) {
    x = document.getElementById("cpdMain_cpdCitizenProfile_txtLoc");
    x.innerHTML = '<p>Dragging ... Marker dropped:Current Lat:' +   evt.latLng.lat() + ' Current Lng: '
    + evt.latLng.lng()  + '</p>';
  });

google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'drag', function (evt) {
    x = document.getElementById("cpdMain_cpdCitizenProfile_txtLoc");
    x.innerHTML = '<p>Dragging ... again .... Marker position: Current Lat: ' + evt.latLng.lat() + ' Current Lng: ' + evt.latLng.lng() + '</p>';
});

google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'dragend', function (evt) {
    x = document.getElementById("cpdMain_cpdCitizenProfile_txtLoc");
    x.innerHTML = '<p>Drag .. ended ... Marker dropped: Current Lat: ' + evt.latLng.lat() + ' Current Lng: ' + evt.latLng.lng() + '</p>';
    geocodePosition(marker.getPosition());
});

 }
```

Comment: x.innerHtml -> x.value. Have you tried this?

Comment: There is valueof() not value.

Comment: use *value*. IntelliSense will not give you that, but it works

Comment: What is exactly the problem.. the map is not visible?... if is possibile and the code is not too big show me also the html code..related..

Comment: the map is visible but it does not pass the location to textbox on dragging the marker

Comment: Its working now, I didnot change anything. Only thing is I am not able to do is when the user enters the location in textbox and clicks on button the marker should point at that place